# How to select a random record from a MySQL database?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using the following query to select 1 random record -

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM table ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

but it gives me the same set of records every time I call it. How do I get better random record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This will not perform well for large number of records.